Large file not pushing to GitHub
I added a file (.mlpackage) of 774.96MB to my project, and it won't push to github because it exceeds their 100MB file limit.
As instructed by my terminal, I've used git lfs, however the file still isn't pushing to github.
(base) anousheh@Anoushehs-MBP TextSum % git lfs track "*.bin"

"*.bin" already supported

(base) anousheh@Anoushehs-MBP TextSum % git add TextSum/Bartt.mlpackage/Data/com.apple.CoreML/weights/weight.bin
(base) anousheh@Anoushehs-MBP TextSum % git add .gitattributes
(base) anousheh@Anoushehs-MBP TextSum % git commit -m "large file"
[main 4f6c864] large file
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
(base) anousheh@Anoushehs-MBP TextSum % git push
Uploading LFS objects: 100% (1/1), 813 MB | 0 B/s, done.                                                                      
Enumerating objects: 31, done.
Counting objects: 100% (31/31), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (21/21), done.
Writing objects: 100% (27/27), 716.51 MiB | 2.16 MiB/s, done.
Total 27 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5/5), completed with 2 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: de8775feac2b29bcbbcb2398184f2c724ff5a37088d013a57862efd648ddc3e5
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File TextSum/Bartt.mlpackage/Data/com.apple.CoreML/weights/weight.bin is 774.96 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/x
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/x'

I believe I followed the instructions on the git lfs website pretty much to the T, so I'm a bit confused as to why my files still aren't pushing to github. If anyone knows what's going wrong here, I would really appreciate the help!

you need to remove from history blobs that are larger than 100 MBs (restriction on the provider side).... alternatively, you could consider using git-lfs, as the message from github tips you.

Thank you so much - that solved my problem :)
